# Adding numbers to a TexView from Listview multiple choice

Tags: java, android, textview

I have one array that is displayed in a listview and one textview. I want that every item is selected on the list view, add a value to a counter that is displayed in the textview. For example if I select "THREE" in the listView, the texview must show "Value is 3", and if I also select "TWO", the texview shows "Value is 5" (3 + 2).

I have made a second listview_array with values that I have tried to pass to integer, but its not working. Any idea or help please?

This is the code for my question:

```
package com.javaya.proyecto002;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

 ;

public class activity2 extends Activity {

    TextView tv1;
    ListView lv1;
    int counter;
    int counter2;
    String listview_array[] = { "ONE", "TWO", "THREE", "FOUR", "FIVE", "SIX",
            "SEVEN", "EIGHT", "NINE", "TEN" };
    String listview_array2[] = { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6",
            "7", "8", "9", "10" };

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity2);

        tv1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1); 
        counter = 0;
        lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        lv1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1, listview_array));
        lv1.setChoiceMode(lv1.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
        lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

        private String[] listview_array2 = { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6",
                "7", "8", "9", "10" };

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long id){

         if (lv1.isItemChecked(position)); String name = this.listview_array2[position];
          counter2 = Integer.parseInt(name);
          counter = counter + counter2;
          tv1.setText("Total " + counter);


        }
                                        });

    }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
String name = listview_array2.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
```

use:

```
String name = this.listview_array2[position];
```

Comment: thank you! It´s been very useful. Now the texview changes properly and shows the number. But still the values are not being added, it only shows the last item selected....

Comment: The way you are doing, every time you click, the counter is reseted to 0. Try to reallocate `counter = 0;` right after `onCreate()`. It has to be outside of `onItemClick()`

Comment: That has been also very useful! Thank you! But I still have a problem; now, every time an Item is Checked add the value to the total, regardless it has been previously checked. I mean, I only want the item to add the value if it is checked, and when it is unchecked I need the value to be remove from the total in the TextView

Comment: inside of `onItemClick()` you have to somehow check if the item have being check `if(listview_array2.isItemChecked(position)`, if it is you count, otherwise remove it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. With that change, now it doesn`t add the value when I uncheck the item, only remain the same. I would like that when I uncheck an Item, the value were remove from the total... I don´t know if i am explaining myself properly, sorry for my english

Comment: May I change from "itemclicklistener" to "ItemSelectedListener"? Does it make sense?

Comment: Hello everyone! I was trying to do something like this, and I found thid post. 

I would like to know if you finally get it, por someone could finally get the answer. 

Thanks.